# run python script from command line and then enter interactive mode

Tags: python, command-line

Is there a way to run a python module from command line ( -m option, which imports and runs a module ), and then enter the interactive mode?

I need something similar to "cmd /k command".

I tested the -i option, but it didn't work; I'm not sure but it seems just redirects in_stream from input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `-i` before the `-m`.

The `-m` option is an interface option; it terminates the option list and all subsequent arguments will end up in `sys.argv` for the module's `main` function. ([link to doc](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html))

Answer (score 1):

Or go into interactive mode and run your python file:

```
import <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*bpython*](http://bpython-interpreter.org/) in the following way:

```
bpython -i <filename>
```

which will load the module and get into interactive mode